# Google Maps v2 - Error inflating class fragment

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-fragments

I am trying to get a Google Map to work within my fragment. I get an error saying it could not inflate the class fragment. I'm not sure what I am doing wrong here. Any ideas? Here is my code:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;

public class MoviesFragment extends Fragment {

private GoogleMap map;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_movies,
            container, false);

    // create map
    map = ((MapFragment) getActivity().getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
            .getMap();

    return rootView;

}

}
```

And here is my layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="info.androidhive.tabsswipe.MoviesFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Logcat:

```
08-21 15:46:27.290: E/AndroidRuntime(4042): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-21 15:46:27.290: E/AndroidRuntime(4042): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class fragment
08-21 15:46:27.290: E/AndroidRuntime(4042):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:713)
08-21 15:46:27.290: E/AndroidRuntime(4042):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
08-21 15:46:27.290: E/AndroidRuntime(4042):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
08-21 15:46:27.290: E/AndroidRuntime(4042):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
08-21 15:46:27.290: E/AndroidRuntime(4042):     at info.androidhive.tabsswipe.MoviesFragment.onCreateView(MoviesFragment.java:20)
08-21 15:46:27.290: E/AndroidRuntime(4042):     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1478)
08-21 15:46:27.290: E/AndroidRuntime(4042):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:927)
08-21 15:46:27.290: E/AndroidRuntime(4042):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
08-21 15:46:27.290: E/AndroidRuntime(4042):     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
08-21 15:46:27.290: E/AndroidRuntime(4042):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1460)
08-21 15:46:27.290: E/AndroidRuntime(4042):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:472)
08-21 15:46:27.290: E/AndroidRuntime(4042):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:141)
08-21 15:46:27.290: E/AndroidRuntime(4042):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1068)
08-21 15:46:27.290: E/AndroidRuntime(4042):     at     android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:914)
08-21 15:46:27.290: E/AndroidRuntime(4042):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1436)
08-21 15:46:27.290: E/AndroidRuntime(4042):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15855)
08-21 15:46:27.290: E/AndroidRuntime(4042):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5012)
08-21 15:46:27.290: E/AndroidRuntime(4042):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
08-21 15:46:27.290: E/AndroidRuntime(4042):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15855)
08-21 15:46:27.290: E/AndroidRuntime(4042):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5012)
08-21 15:46:27.290: E/AndroidRuntime(4042):     at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:302)
08-21 15:46:27.290: E/AndroidRuntime(4042):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15855)
08-21 15:46:27.290: E/AndroidRuntime(4042):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5012)
08-21 15:46:27.290: E/AndroidRuntime(4042):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
08-21 15:46:27.290: E/AndroidRuntime(4042):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2451)
08-21 15:46:27.290: E/AndroidRuntime(4042):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15855)
08-21 15:46:27.290: E/AndroidRuntime(4042):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1905)
08-21 15:46:27.290: E/AndroidRuntime(4042):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1104)
08-21 15:46:27.290: E/AndroidRuntime(4042):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1284)
08-21 15:46:27.290: E/AndroidRuntime(4042):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1004)
08-21 15:46:27.290: E/AndroidRuntime(4042):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5481)
08-21 15:46:27.290: E/AndroidRuntime(4042):     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
08-21 15:46:27.290: E/AndroidRuntime(4042):     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
08-21 15:46:27.290: E/AndroidRuntime(4042):     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532)
08-21 15:46:27.290: E/AndroidRuntime(4042):     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
08-21 15:46:27.290: E/AndroidRuntime(4042):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
08-21 15:46:27.290: E/AndroidRuntime(4042):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
08-21 15:46:27.290: E/AndroidRuntime(4042):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-21 15:46:27.290: E/AndroidRuntime(4042):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5289)
08-21 15:46:27.290: E/AndroidRuntime(4042):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-21 15:46:27.290: E/AndroidRuntime(4042):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
08-21 15:46:27.290: E/AndroidRuntime(4042):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:739)
08-21 15:46:27.290: E/AndroidRuntime(4042):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:555)
08-21 15:46:27.290: E/AndroidRuntime(4042):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-21 15:46:27.290: E/AndroidRuntime(4042): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment cannot be cast to android.support.v4.app.Fragment
08-21 15:46:27.290: E/AndroidRuntime(4042):     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:402)
08-21 15:46:27.290: E/AndroidRuntime(4042):     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:377)
08-21 15:46:27.290: E/AndroidRuntime(4042):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:277)
08-21 15:46:27.290: E/AndroidRuntime(4042):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:685)
```

Comment: Use SupportMapFragment as you are using v4.app.Fragment.

Comment: I have using SupportMapFragment but it still gives the same error

Comment: can you show the error which you are getting in the logcat?

Comment: @amitsingh logcat is posted

Comment: don't have `name` and `class` in your Fragment XML choose 1 or the other

Comment: @Blundell still not working, though

Comment: @Harry try my given solution.

Answer (score 0):

In xml, write this-

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
```

In Java class file, write this-

```
map = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
```

Its because, you are using `v4.app.Fragment`. So, you have to use `getSupportFragmentManager()`.

Comment: I have done this, unfortunately I still get the exact same error

Comment: Since you are using Support library v4 compatible with lower version of android. Replace MapFragment with SupportMapFragment inside your xml file and in java file and then it should work.

Comment: @Harry in this case, the error must be different, can you show that error?