# Is there any method to use facebook SDK for Android without android-support-v4?

Tags: android, facebook, android-support-library, facebook-android-sdk

As you probably know the facebook sdk requires android-support-v4 by default. But I am building the software for Android version 3.0 (API level 11) and higher. So I do not need this support library. Nevertheless it required for facebook sdk. Is there any method to use facebook SDK without android-support-v4?
Thank you!

Best Regards
Ekaterina

Comment: If you want to use `facebook SDK` without support library, then you need to check in SDK whether there is any dependency of that in the facebook SDK.

Comment: there is "import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;" in FacebookButtonBase I have found here https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/blob/master/facebook/src/main/java/com/facebook/FacebookButtonBase.java since that I decide that Facebook SDK doesn't work without android-support-v4 . How to get rid of that library completely?

Comment: Are you developing for Android version 1.5 (API level 3) or for Android version 3.0 (API level 11)?

Comment: As I said I developing for Android version 3 and hight. Yes, API level 11 and higher.

Comment: I'd recommend you DO use the support library, even though it has copies of `Fragment` etc they will be superior in terms of bug fixes, it's always recommended to use it

Comment: I see. But I want to GET RID OF this library and want to know is it possible or not? Seems like it is not possible. Very sad. I can't use android.app.Fragment in my specific application thus, because of compatibility issues (I need strictly android.app.Fragment  everywhere in my app ).

Comment: @EkaterinaI. Once try with compiling and check

Comment: It is very simple: I can't assign fragment to login button: loginButton.setFragment(this); it does not compile when "this" is android.app.Fragment instance instead of android.support.v4.app.Fragment .

Comment: @Blundell for example this kind of issue http://stackoverflow.com/a/25434871/5659880